Failing to send more than one image in cloudinary
im using the following code to send a array of images to cloudinary, but the code is always sending the last image, even though all console.logs shows all the images, it seem like its all fine, so i dont know what to do, im also showing some images to provide more infos of my problem:
"use client";

import { useDropzone } from "react-dropzone";
import styles from "../../styles/Home.module.css";
import { useCallback, useState, useMemo } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function DropZone() {
  const [selectedImages, setSelectedImages] = useState([]);
  const [uploadStatus, setUploadStatus] = useState("");
  const onDrop = useCallback((acceptedFiles: any, rejectedFiles: any) => {
    setSelectedImages((prevState): any => [...prevState, ...acceptedFiles]);
  }, []);

  const {
    getRootProps,
    getInputProps,
    isDragActive,
    isDragAccept,
    isDragReject,
  } = useDropzone({ onDrop });

  const onUpload = async () => {
    console.log(selectedImages); // shows all the images 
    setUploadStatus("Uploading....");
    const formData = new FormData();
    selectedImages.forEach((image) => {
      formData.append("file", image);
    });
    formData.append('upload_preset', 'w1ro2bph');
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/df57qohob/image/upload', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
      });
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to upload images');
      }
      const responseData = await response.json();
      console.log(responseData); // also shows all the images
      setUploadStatus("Upload successful");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("imageUpload", error);
      setUploadStatus("Upload failed");
    }
  };

  const style = useMemo(
    () => ({
      ...(isDragAccept ? { borderColor: "#00e676" } : {}),
      ...(isDragReject ? { borderColor: "#ff1744" } : {}),
    }),
    [isDragAccept, isDragReject]
  );






You are overwriting each file with a new one.
Please also take a look at the example here:
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/client_side_uploading#code_explorer_upload_multiple_files_using_a_form_unsigned
-Tamara
